# How can I access a blob from one domain to other on CLIENT side

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, blob, cross-domain

Lets say I have two domains

- abc.com
- xyz.com

I am receiving a blob from server (lets say on abc.com) and thats how I get the url of that blog:

```
    var pdfFile = new Blob([(blob)], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(this.pdfFile);
    this.url = fileURL;
```

Now I have url and all I want is to access that blob from one of my other website (xyz.com) which is hosted on another domain.

When I get the blob in abc.com I open my other website xyz.com in new tab in such way that it has the link of blob. But how can I access that blob using that link?

Currently I am trying this on xyz.com:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'blob:http%3A//abc.com', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var myBlob = this.response;
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

But its giving my error, and ofcourse it is supposed to because of different domains

> Failed to load blob:http://myBlobFullURL Cross origin requests are
>   only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

Comment: are you opening xyz.com using `window.open`?

Answer (score 5):

*Because of StackExchange rules, `abc.com` was replaced with `example.com` and `xyz.com` was replaced with `example.net` ([read more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-https-site-com-and-https-mysite-com-bloc)).*

`blob` URLs cannot be accessed cross-domain, the workaround is to [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) the `Blob` object *([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68556581/why-cant-i-fetch-an-object-url-aka-blob-url-cross-site-and-cross-frame))*.

At `example.com` :

```js
const exampleDotNet = window.open('https://example.net');
// TODO wait for example.net to be ready
exampleDotNet.postMessage(pdfFile, 'https://example.net');
```

At `example.net` :

```js
window.addEventListener(
    'message',
    ({
        origin,
        data: myBlob
    }) => {
        if(origin === 'https://example.com'){
            // TODO something with myBlob
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: great solution, I have one question regarding this. Would this approach be necessary if the target domain is a subdomain of the sender?

Comment: Maybe not, try opening a domain's `blob:` URL from a subdomain of it, and see if an error is thrown.

Comment: blob url didn't end up working when attempted to access through subdomain with the error message 
Not allowed to load local resource: blob:subdomain/[BLOD_ID]

Comment: a follow up question I have is the --to do part you have here? 
how would you go about waiting the example.net to be ready and at least have the eventlistener set ? I tried putting onload listener to the new window ref but also wasn't allowed due to cors rules, I guess an unreliable set timeout is the only way even though it is quite unreliable?

Comment: When `example.net` is ready, you `postMessage` from it to `example.com`.