# Why can't I fetch an object URL (aka "blob URL") cross-site and cross-frame?

Tags: iframe, same-origin-policy, cross-site, createobjecturl

I'm developing an iframeable component and have now stumbled over something that looks like a security problem.

I have two web sites:

- site A, running at http://localhost:3002
- site B, running at http://localhost:3000

Site A embeds site B in an IFrame. Site B needs data to work with, which is supposed to be provided by site A. However, right now site B only accepts data via URLs and since the original URL might need authentication, data is fetched by site A, converted to an object URL (with `URL.createObjectURL`) and then provided to site B via `postMessage`. Site B is now supposed to fetch the data from that URL and work with it.

However, fetching of the object URL by site B is getting blocked by the browser:

- Chrome: `Not allowed to load local resource: blob:http://localhost:3002/<UUID>`
- Firefox: `Security Error: Content at http://localhost:3000/... may not load data from blob:http://localhost:3002/<UUID>`

These message are, as far as I can see, not connected to either CSP or CORS. However, I can't understand what the problem is and whether it is fixable or not -- I have been under the impression that object URLs do not currently have any cross-site problems, which is exactly why the are being used.

So why does it happen and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://github.com/w3c/FileAPI/issues/135 and the references therein. There is a same origin restriction in practice, but this isn't reflected in specifications as of yet. It's unlikely we'll remove that restriction as `blob:` URLs make it easy to create memory leaks. (In fact, we want to place more restrictions on them: https://github.com/w3c/FileAPI/issues/153 .)

If you have a `postMessage()` API you'll need to extend it whereby you either message a URL or an object. Messaging the `Blob` instance itself should work.

Comment: Thanks, this settles it, I guess. If I understand you correctly, there is no setting or a header like ` Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which would lift the restriction?

Comment: No, that does not (and will not, I suspect) exist.